# Get the total sales

Tags: javascript

I created a function that will return an object of no duplicate branch and the total sales per branch.

```
    var salesPersons = [
        {"name": {"first": "Aleen", "last" :"Atkins"}, "sales" : "$2314", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Alvaro", "last" :"Angelos"}, "sales" : "$1668", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Denese", "last" :"Dossett"}, "sales" : "$9248", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Douglas", "last" :"Denney"}, "sales" : "$5058", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Earline", "last" :"Erickson"}, "sales" : "$18876", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Herman", "last" :"Hazell"}, "sales" : "$2746", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Homer", "last" :"Hirth"}, "sales" : "$474", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
        {"name": {"first": "Hwa", "last" :"Heidt"}, "sales" : "$9607", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
        {"name": {"first": "Hyon", "last" :"Hampshire"}, "sales" : "$13598", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Issac", "last" :"Ingerson"}, "sales" : "$5225", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Jeraldine", "last" :"Joplin"}, "sales" : "$2891", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Jin", "last" :"Jeffrey"}, "sales" : "$14402", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Joleen", "last" :"Jolin"}, "sales" : "$15736", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Jude", "last" :"Jarrett"}, "sales" : "$7557", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
        {"name": {"first": "Magda", "last" :"Mireles"}, "sales" : "$1498", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
        {"name": {"first": "Mistie", "last" :"Montealegre"}, "sales" : "$6920", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Nancy", "last" :"Napoli"}, "sales" : "$5255", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Regine", "last" :"Rohrbaugh"}, "sales" : "$7881", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
        {"name": {"first": "Rolando", "last" :"Riebel"}, "sales" : "$8573", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
        {"name": {"first": "Scarlett", "last" :"Stagg"}, "sales" : "$7126", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
        {"name": {"first": "Sherron", "last" :"Strawn"}, "sales" : "$8848", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
        {"name": {"first": "Susan", "last" :"Shilling"}, "sales" : "$8542", "branch": "Seattle, WA"},
        {"name": {"first": "Tama", "last" :"Tworek"}, "sales" : "$9200", "branch": "Seattle, WA"},
        {"name": {"first": "Tonisha", "last" :"Taunton"}, "sales" : "$5219", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
        {"name": {"first": "Vergie", "last" :"Villescas"}, "sales" : "$8712", "branch": "New York City, NY"}
    ];

    function convertSalesToInt(person){
      var salesInt = person.sales.slice(1);
      return parseInt(salesInt, 10);
    }

    function salesPerBranch(salesPersons){
    var myObj = {};
    var uniq = [];
    var total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < salesPersons.length; i++){
      var splitTeam = salesPersons[i].branch;
      if(uniq.indexOf(salesPersons) < 0){
        myObj[salesPersons] = total+= convertSalesToInt(salesPersons[i]);
      }
    }

    return myObj;


    }

    console.log(salesPerBranch(salesPersons));
    /* { 'Austin, TX': 110898,
  'New York City, NY': 187174,
  'Orlando, FL': 178462,
  'San Francisco, CA': 139527,
  'Seattle, WA': 173243 } */
```

The answer should look like this:

```
{
    'Austin, TX': 48423,
    'New York City, NY': 74572,
    'Orlando, FL': 20700,
    'San Francisco, CA': 25737,
    'Seattle, WA': 17742
}
```

The only part where I am stuck right now is the part where I add the total sales for each branch. Right now it's not pulling up the right amount. This part is responsible for that:

```
if(uniq.indexOf(salesPersons) < 0){
        myObj[salesPersons] = total+= convertSalesToInt(salesPersons[i]);
      }
```

Anyone who know what my mistakes and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var salesPersons = [
    {"name": {"first": "Aleen", "last" :"Atkins"}, "sales" : "$2314", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Alvaro", "last" :"Angelos"}, "sales" : "$1668", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Denese", "last" :"Dossett"}, "sales" : "$9248", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Douglas", "last" :"Denney"}, "sales" : "$5058", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Earline", "last" :"Erickson"}, "sales" : "$18876", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Herman", "last" :"Hazell"}, "sales" : "$2746", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Homer", "last" :"Hirth"}, "sales" : "$474", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
    {"name": {"first": "Hwa", "last" :"Heidt"}, "sales" : "$9607", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
    {"name": {"first": "Hyon", "last" :"Hampshire"}, "sales" : "$13598", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Issac", "last" :"Ingerson"}, "sales" : "$5225", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Jeraldine", "last" :"Joplin"}, "sales" : "$2891", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Jin", "last" :"Jeffrey"}, "sales" : "$14402", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Joleen", "last" :"Jolin"}, "sales" : "$15736", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Jude", "last" :"Jarrett"}, "sales" : "$7557", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
    {"name": {"first": "Magda", "last" :"Mireles"}, "sales" : "$1498", "branch": "Austin, TX"},
    {"name": {"first": "Mistie", "last" :"Montealegre"}, "sales" : "$6920", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Nancy", "last" :"Napoli"}, "sales" : "$5255", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Regine", "last" :"Rohrbaugh"}, "sales" : "$7881", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
    {"name": {"first": "Rolando", "last" :"Riebel"}, "sales" : "$8573", "branch": "San Francisco, CA"},
    {"name": {"first": "Scarlett", "last" :"Stagg"}, "sales" : "$7126", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
    {"name": {"first": "Sherron", "last" :"Strawn"}, "sales" : "$8848", "branch": "New York City, NY"},
    {"name": {"first": "Susan", "last" :"Shilling"}, "sales" : "$8542", "branch": "Seattle, WA"},
    {"name": {"first": "Tama", "last" :"Tworek"}, "sales" : "$9200", "branch": "Seattle, WA"},
    {"name": {"first": "Tonisha", "last" :"Taunton"}, "sales" : "$5219", "branch": "Orlando, FL"},
    {"name": {"first": "Vergie", "last" :"Villescas"}, "sales" : "$8712", "branch": "New York City, NY"}
];

function convertSalesToInt(person){
  var salesInt = person.sales.slice(1);
  return parseInt(salesInt, 10);
}

function salesPerBranch(salesPersons){
  var myObj = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < salesPersons.length; i++){
    var splitTeam = salesPersons[i].branch;
    myObj[splitTeam] = myObj[splitTeam] ? myObj[splitTeam]: 0;
    myObj[splitTeam] += convertSalesToInt(salesPersons[i]);
  }

  return myObj;
}

console.log(salesPerBranch(salesPersons));
```

You need to check if you don't have sales count data then make it zero, if you have then add to it.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to understand a part of your answer because I'm weak with objects. For this line , " myObj[splitTeam] = myObj[splitTeam] ? myObj[splitTeam]: 0;" ; Is this is equivalent to "if (myObj[splitTeam]) return myObj[splitTeam]:0 right? Is it just one expression being returned? I'm used to seeing 2 expressions with ternary operators.

Comment: this`myObj[splitTeam] = myObj[splitTeam] ? myObj[splitTeam]: 0;` is equal to `if(myObj[splitTeam]){ myObj[splitTeam] = myObj[splitTeam]}else{ myObj[splitTeam] = 0}` , Did this because when we are adding one object for first time the value will be undefind, so i am setting it to 0, if value is there then adding with that value.

Comment: Also one more thing, does the object know to skip duplicates by itself? In his array, he has objects with duplicate properties. Does the object just skip that and only take unique properties? Thanks alot for the explanation.

Comment: in object while adding {key,value}, it checks for existing keys, if key present it replace the value, if not it creates another field with key,value.

Comment: sorry if it was my question, I would. i upvoted the answer a long time ago.

Comment: @Dream_Cap my bad , i was referring to him. will remove that :P

Comment: upvote and accept answer, if this what you wanted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another a slightly different way inspired by @Durga's answer. I used the for...of loop and a simplified if statement to understand his answer.

```
   function salesPerBranch(salesPersons) {
      var myObj = {};

      //loop through sales people
      for (let person of salesPersons) {
        let branch = person.branch;

        //test for branches
        if (!myObj[branch]) {
          //create branches in the obj
          myObj[branch] = myObj[branch]
            //set default value to 0
          myObj[branch] = 0;

        }
        //Add sales for each branch
        myObj[branch] += convertSalesToInt(person);

      }
      console.log(myObj)

    }

     salesPerBranch(salesPersons);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
salesPersons.map(function(x){return x.branch}).filter(function(value, index, self){return self.indexOf(value) === index;}).forEach(function(x){
        console.log(x + ' : $' + salesPersons.filter(function(y){if(y.branch === x) return y}).map(function(z){return z.sales.slice(1)}).reduce(function(a,b){return +a + +b;},0));
    });
```